# Is pac-man still protected by copyright?

Tags: pacman

I am planning to write and distribute a pac-man like game. So I would like to know if It is still protected by copyright.

Can I use the word pacman in the title? What are the limits that I will have?

PS. I can conclude from the first answers that I can't use the name and may be a very similar art work. If I keep that in mind, will I have any trouble. And I don't want to do something unethical, is it unethical to write a pac-man like game? I see tons of them on the internet.

Comment: you could create a Pac-woman game :)

Comment: ethically I see nothing wrong if you're not trying to make a profit from it

Answer (score 7):

It's a matter of [trademarks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trademark#Maintaining_rights), not copyright. Trademarks don't run out, though they must be continually used. I'm pretty sure Pacman would be considered to be in use, as it's a very well-known brand.

So you'll have to use a different name.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So what I have to do is to use a different name and art work.

Comment: @h.world43: definitely different name. Artwork is copyright, which can run out, but the lifetime is much more than the age of Pacman. IN 100 years, it might be a different story...

Comment: I would call it "wokka", the sound it used to make while moving: wokka wokka wokka ...

Answer (score 6):

A visit to [Namco](http://www.namcogames.com/) will show you they are still actively promoting it by porting it to new platforms, as well as continuing to develop it as a franchise.

So the answer is: No. No. Also, no.

Comment: Just the name - or the game itself though?

Answer (score -1):

I think no??? since this is game we are seeing since childhood so , you cannot use its name. And its the most popular game in world, just like mario, tetris etc. So better dont use names that exists from decades instead use some other similiar type names, if you want.